# How to fix the Error of "No module named 'adler'"

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, module, package

Could anyone please help with fixing the following error when trying to run "import adler.tensorflow as atf"?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adler'

Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you give more details such how did you install the package, did you use pip or just copy a Github repo. Because the error messege is very specific: there is no module to import.

Comment: @SaschaKirch  Thank you for your comment. I used pip. How to fix the error of "No module named 'adler'"?  Thanks.

Comment: I could not find a package named Adler on PyPi hence !pip install adler did not work for me. I just found the „alder“. Maybe you just have a typo :)

Comment: There is no package named "Adler"Please share some more code details on this to find the exact issue.